# close javafx login window after successfull login

Tags: javafx

I have create JavaFX login window that after log in into main window the login window will be closed.

I use `Platform.exit();` but it exit from entire application instead of login window.

I can't access to stage from controller class. I am using `closeLogin()` method below but it doesn't work for me. This is my LoginController class:

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txt_username;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField txt_password;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_login;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_cancel;
    Stage stage1 = null;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @FXML
    private void btn_login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Library.fxml"));
        Stage page1Stage = new Stage();
        page1Stage.setResizable(false);
        page1Stage.setTitle("Main Form ");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        page1Stage.setScene(scene);
        /*

         Some codes

         */
        page1Stage.show();
        closeLogin();
    }

    public void closeLogin() {
        stage1 = (Stage) stage1.getScene().getWindow();
        stage1.close();
    }

    @FXML
    public void cancelButtonAction() {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `close()` of [`Stage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html). [Platform.exit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--) will terminate the JavaFX application.

```
loginWindow.close();
```

where `loginWindow` is the stage you want to close.

**Update**

You can try to get instance of `Stage` from `stage1` which has not been initialized yet. Using

```
stage1.getScene().getWindow();
```

should throw `NullPointerException`.

Try getting an instance of `Window` from the `TextField` or the `Button`, which are already present on the scene graph.

```
public void closeLogin() {
     stage1 = (Stage) btn_login.getScene().getWindow();
     stage1.close();
}
```